# img adress linked in href tag not opened in chrome

Tags: html, href

[To see the apple image when click on link no image show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BIFv.png)

I want the problem has been solved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>listoffruits</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List of Fruits</h1>
    <ul>

        <li>Apple <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">seea apple</a></li>


    </ul>
</body>
</html>


Here is the code please solve it
```

Comment: you need the `img` tag inside the `a` tag.

Comment: What image-url is this? Even in CDNs I've never seen this much big image-url anywhere.

Comment: @SuramuthuR It's base 64 image. The whole image contained in this String, it's not a url. It's most likely not a good idel though, it make big html files, slow to serve and image are not cached...

Comment: Thank you. But what is the purpose of using like this? If it is something to do with the safety, How it could be? Because, By right-clicking the link & copying the link address and pasting in you new browser window, The image is opening. Again I could download the image using 'Save Image as'.